# How to put a redirect url that has PathVariable to it in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

I tried to find on how to redirect the link from the controller of Spring MVC but I only found the solution if the link doesn't have PathVariable.

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="dokter/update/{idDokter}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changeDokterFormSubmit(@PathVariable Long idDokter, @ModelAttribute DokterModel dokter, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
        System.err.println(request.getParameter("Tanggal lahir"));
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date date = sdf.parse(request.getParameter("Tanggal lahir"));
        dokter.setTanggalLahir(date);
        System.err.println(dokter.getTempatLahir());
        dokter.setNik(dokter.getNik());
        DokterModel newDokterData = dokterService.changeDokter(dokter);
        model.addAttribute("dokter", newDokterData);
        return "redirect:'/dokter/view/'+${newDokterData.getNik()}";
    }
```

where this is the method that I want to reach.

```
 @RequestMapping("/dokter/view/{nikDokter}")
    private String detilDokter(
            @PathVariable String nikDokter,
            Model model
    ){
        DokterModel dokter = dokterService.getDokterByNik(nikDokter).get();
        Boolean gender = dokter.getJenisKelamin();
        String result = "Laki-laki";
        if(gender){
            result = "Perempuan";
        }
        model.addAttribute("dokter", dokter);
        model.addAttribute("gender", result);
        model.addAttribute("spesialis", spesialisService);
        return "detil-dokter";
    }
```

When i tried that, i got this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model has no value for key 'newDokterData.getNik()'
```

But the POST itself actually works, as the data itself changed perfectly fine. How should I approach this problem?

**BONUS**

For future reference if my detilDokter method is like this.

```
@RequestMapping("/dokter")
    private String detilDokter(
            @RequestParam String nikDokter,
            Model model
    ){
        DokterModel dokter = dokterService.getDokterByNik(nikDokter).get();
        Boolean gender = dokter.getJenisKelamin();
        String result = "Laki-laki";
        if(gender){
            result = "Perempuan";
        }
        model.addAttribute("dokter", dokter);
        model.addAttribute("gender", result);
        model.addAttribute("spesialis", spesialisService);
        return "detil-dokter";
    }
```

How does the redirect should look like in changeDokterFormSubmit?

Comment: You could try `return "redirect:'/dokter/view/'+${dokter.getNik()}";` - since that is the attribute name you get `newDokterData` in your model ...

Comment: @moilejter I have tried that and it has similar error
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model has no value for key 'dokter.getNik()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
int or String p1="1";
int or String p2="1";

return "redirect:/abc/xyz/"+p1;

return "redirect:/abc/xyz/"+p1+"/"+p2;
```

Comment: This works perfectly like how i wanted to be, thanks!